# jQuery ajax call never finishes (success and error callbacks are not fired)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

I've an ajax request to the server and I only need to know when it finishes to redirect the user to a second page. **It is working most of the times** but if the server takes too long to answer (e.g. 10 min) then it can happen that no callback function is called and the request keeps waiting.

My code is as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'request.php',
      success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: "+data);
            window.location.replace("success.php");
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Ajax error: "+xhr.status+" - "+thrownError);
            window.location.replace("error.php");
      }
});
```

As you can see, I've tried to check if there is any error but as far as I have arrived, the ajax request behaves as if it had not finished (no alert or redirection is fired). However, the PHP code in the server runs without errors until the end.

I have no idea where to search for the error because I was thinking about a timeout problem both in the browser or in the server but it seems not to be the cause. And as the same code is working in short waiting times I cannot imagine other possible reasons.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the network console show anything interesting? Does the browser see the request ever finish?

Comment: You need to sprinkle error logging code throughout the back-end PHP script. That's the likely candidate for the holdup, and since you can't output anything visually from it, the error_log is the way to go. That, and the console as has already been suggested.

Comment: "same code is working in short waiting times" and this means? 10 minutes for a page response, really?

Comment: You can set $.ajax's `timeout` option but be sure to read the text for timeout [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Comment: if you have chrome, check `network` tab in developer console. You can see if there are server side errors there...

Comment: As `Mr. Gordon Freeman` said.. There might be some error on `php` side :)

Comment: @JanDvorak console doesn't show anything at all. I've tried also adding a postComplete=true/false flag variable in both callback functions, and it never changes its value.

Comment: @GordonFreeman correct me if I'm wrong but if there is any serverside warning/error shouldn't I receive it as the data in my ajax request? Btw, at the end of the PHP code I initialize a session variable just to check if its value is changed and it is. I'll try the network tab in the console.

Comment: @Maverick no server side errors showed in the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet on a timeout on your web server which invalidates the connection, this might mean that no answer is sent back.
In that case, the ajax timeout option might be good for you.

Having said that, if I were you, I would do this differently: since you're already using ajax, why not ping the server every x seconds and check if the process has finished and it's time to redirect, instead of keeping the connection open?  This way you don't have timeout issues, and you don't hold the connection captive over a session which doesn't send any data and only waits for a server side process to finish.  More scalable and robust, and more appropriate for http connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As pointed, I've solved the problem by asking the server every x seconds if the process has finished. 

But still, as I understand, this means that the server behaves invalidating the connection without answering but letting the code execution to continue? Where can I find this serverside connection  timeout? Can I force to send something to the browser if the connection is closed by the server?

Comment: processes that take a long time to operate should be executed in a separate thread than the process which answers http connections.  this means that the answer to such a request should have the meaning of "got it, i'm on it, call me back in a couple of seconds to check up on me", rather than "here's the answer".  This means that if the request is valid and you're looking for the answer, a simple "OK" response should be sent right away (if using ajax), or whatever jsp which has the periodic check if the request was a simple html request. You shouldn't get to the timeout state because the

Comment: response to the original request is a simple "got it" without waiting for the actual answer.